# Multiple storage disk in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have two kind of upload. I wish to keep them separated. This is my attemp, but doesn't work:

**config/filesystems.php**

```
return [
    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'local'),
    'disks' => [  
        'authors' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/authors',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],


        'quotes' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/quotes',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],
    ],

    'links' => [
        public_path('authors') => storage_path('app/authors'),
        public_path('quotes') => storage_path('app/quotes'),
    ],

];
```

**app/Nova/Author.php**

```
Avatar::make('Avatar', 'image')
    ->disk('public')
    ->storeAs(function (Request $request) {
        return Str::slug($this->name, '-') . '.' . $request->file('image')->extension();
    })
    ->deletable(true),
```